# Dynamic form rendering and filling the form from a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, dynamic-forms

I'm a newbie still learning angularJS. Can someone help me out?
My assignment is to create dynamic forms where the data comes from a JSON object and pre-populates the fields and also we should be able to add and remove forms. I have attached a sample output image - [What I expect it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RD86I.png)

What I have tried to do -
http://plnkr.co/edit/P8R20LkV5mh8ipqNIsr9?p=info

Where am I going wrong? What changes do I need to make?

```js
var mockDataForThisTest = "json=" + encodeURI(
  JSON.stringify([{
    name: "Dave",
    email: "dave@gmail.com",
    option: "Home",
    number: "1234567890"
  }, {
    name: "John",
    email: "jon@gmail.com",
    option: "Home",
    number: "1234567890"
  }]));

var app = angular.module('angularApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.choices = [];
  $scope.loadChoices = function() {
    var httpRequest = $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: './json/',
      data: mockDataForThisTest

    }).success(function(data, status) {
      $scope.choices = data;
    });
  };

  $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
    $scope.choices.push({
      'id': 'choice' + newItemNo
    });
  };

  $scope.removeChoice = function() {
    var lastItem = $scope.choices.length - 1;
    $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
  };

});
```

```css
fieldset {
  background: #FCFCFC;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
}
.addfields {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
#choicesDisplay {
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgb(227, 250, 227);
  border: 1px solid rgb(171, 239, 171);
  color: rgb(9, 56, 9);
}
.remove {
  background: #C76868;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 21px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 9px;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 100%;
}
input[type="text"],
select {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="angularApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <fieldset data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
      <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="" placeholder="Enter name">
      <input type="text" ng-model="choice.email" name="" placeholder="Enter email">

      <input type="text" ng-model="choice.number" name="" placeholder="Enter mobile number">
      <select ng-model="choice.option">
        <option value>Select</option>
        <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>
        <option value="Office">Office</option>
        <option value="Home">Home</option>
      </select>
      <button class="remove" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>
    </fieldset>
    <button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add fields</button>

    <div id="choicesDisplay">
      {{ choices }}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your plunkr wasn't working because your script tag was pointing to a not existing `app.js` in `index.html` after re-naming `script.js` to `app.js` the plunkr is working.

Your JSON mock seems a bit complicated. You can easily add a json file to the plunkr and load it with a `$http.get()` request.

Please have a look at the demo below and this [updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/klCx13NmuHFJC7B6fv00?p=preview).

```js
// Code goes here

/*
var mockDataForThisTest = "json=" + encodeURI(
    JSON.stringify([
    {
        name: "Dave",
        email: "dave@gmail.com",
        option: "Home",
        number: "1234567890"
    },
    {
        name: "John",
        email: "jon@gmail.com",
        option: "Home",
        number: "1234567890"
    }
]));*/

var app = angular.module('angularApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.choices = [];
    
    loadChoices();
    
    function loadChoices() {
        var httpRequest = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5758817a130000f82d896c76'
            //url: './example.json'
            //data: mockDataForThisTest

        }).then(function(response) { //success(function(data, status) {
            // use then --> newer syntax
            console.log(response.data);
            $scope.choices = response.data;
        });
    };

    $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
        var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
        $scope.choices.push({
            'id': 'choice' + newItemNo
        });
    };

    $scope.removeChoice = function(index) {
        //var lastItem = $scope.choices.length - 1;
        $scope.choices.splice(index, 1); //lastItem);
    };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div ng-app="angularApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <fieldset data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
            <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="" placeholder="Enter name">
            <input type="text" ng-model="choice.email" name="" placeholder="Enter email">
            
            <input type="text" ng-model="choice.number" name="" placeholder="Enter mobile number">
            <select ng-model="choice.option">
                <option value>Select</option>
                <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>
                <option value="Office">Office</option>
                <option value="Home">Home</option>
            </select>
            <button class="remove" ng-click="removeChoice($index)">-</button>
        </fieldset>
        <button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add fields</button>

        <div id="choicesDisplay">
            {{ choices }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you AWolf. I understood my mistake. Thanks again for helping out.